# how to enable and use the auto-populated grayed out commit message in "Commit Changes" section, for the respective commit?

Tags: github

how to enable and use the auto-populated grayed out commit message in "Commit Changes" section, instead of typing it again for the respective commit?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By clicking on the "**Commit Changes**" button without **overriding** the auto-populated grayed out commit message in "Commit Changes" text box.